# Are there equations to match power required to mass for rotorcraft?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, rotorcraft, airframe-and-powerplant

Is there an equation (or table or whatever) to determine what power is required to fly certain mass? Probably there will be a bunch of nuances, but at least some sort of rule of thumb probably exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is using the [momentum theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_theory), by which the thrust $T$ generated by a rotor is:

$ T = k\sqrt[3]{2 \rho A P^2} $

where $A$ is the rotor area, $\rho$ is the density and $P$ the power needed to spin the rotor. This equation is strictly valid only at hover but being the highest thrust normally required in hover, then it's just perfect for your purpose. The $k$ is a coefficient taking into account limitations of the momentum theory and "*bunch of other nuances*" : a value of $0.5$ can be used in a conservative way.

Obviously $T$ equals weight $ T = W = mg $, where $m$ is the mass and $g$ the gravity.

If you have some numbers in mind we can plug them in and see what we get

Comment: Thank you, ill post an excel graph for sanity check

Comment: @sophit, The cube root does not render well on my browser.  You might change to $()^{1/3}$ instead.

Comment: @RobMcDonald: I've used "\sqrt[3]" which should be the standard way to render the cube root, no idea why it doesn't work properly, thanks anyway for pointing that out 

Comment: OK, here is what i get. https://pasteboard.co/BRRPEZr0dDNW.png  It's power in megawatts against mass in kg. The steps are due to propellers total area i assumed (50 to 500 m^2). Seems reasonable for 1 ton, but for 20t seems like ten times what i expected. What do you think?

Comment: @sophit would you like to consult me for a fee? I don't see private messaging here, if you are willing to talk, I'll post my email here

Comment: I'd plot one line per each disk area so to have a clear view without steps. I'd suggest you also to get a copy of the legendary [Helicopter Aerodynamics](https://books.google.com/books/about/Helicopter_Aerodynamics_Volume_I.html?id=rxryAgAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y) by [Raymond W. Prouty](https://vertipedia.vtol.org/biographies/getBiography/biographyID/88). Very easy to read, fluent and almost without equations. Which project do you have in mind actually? 

Comment: Let's talk offline, please. Email me at lapserdak # gmail * com, i really want to have a consultation with someone who understands the matter 

Comment: @sophit what time zone are you in?

Comment: I got it now, it went to spam. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In a hover, the figure of merit $FM$ is defined as the ratio of the ideal power required to the actual power required.

$FM=\frac{P_\mathrm{ideal}}{P}$

Typical values for the figure of merit are about 0.7.

Momentum theory tells us the ideal power required in a hover.  We can combine these to give the hover power required.

$P=\frac{T\sqrt{T/(2\,\rho\,A)}}{FM}$

Where:

$P$ is the hover power required.

$T$ is the thrust.  In hover, thrust equals weight.

$\rho$ is the density of the air.

$A$ is the disk area.

$T/A$ is the disk loading.

More power is required to climb.  More power is required to power the tail rotor to offset the torque of the main rotor.  More power is required to overcome the drag of the fuselage.

Power required for forward flight gets substantially more complex.

There are equations to calculate or estimate all of these things.  That is what aerospace engineers do.  [Johnson's Helicopter Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486682307) is probably the most comprehensive and least expensive.  However, it is an intense book -- not for the faint of heart.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you very much!

Comment: would you be able to consult me? I'd pay for your time

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to take on more consulting clients at this time.

Comment: Thank you anyway!